# How can I remove the magnifying glass button from an Ant Design input search box?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Is it possible to remove the search button with the magnifying glass on the right of an Input.Search of ant design, so that only the input field is left, maybe by inserting the magnifying glass on the left (with a SearchOutlined prefix)?

```
<Search placeholder="input search text" onSearch={onSearch} style={{ width: 200 }}/>
```

I wish the result was something like

[image: this]

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a specific reason why you need to use `Input.Search`? This can be achieved with a plain `Input` component.

```
<Input prefix={<SearchOutlined />} placeholder="Search..." onPressEnter={onSearch} style={{ width: 200 }} />
```

Comment: `onPressEnter` does not accept the type of `onSearch` . How can we make this work in TS?